# linux - how to change the $ back to the # after the prompt

Tags: linux

I searched the Q and As and didn't find the answer to my basic (novice) question.
What do I need to do to change the $ after the prompt back to the #  ? I don't know what I did but somewhere between [root@server1 root]# man whoami and [root@server1 root]# man -k usb the # changed to a ? I don't know how to change it back.
Thank you for your help,
Anna

Answer (score 2):

You log out from the root account. `exit` or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd>. If you want to stay logged in as root, you can explicitly control the prompt with [PS1](http://www.linuxselfhelp.com/howtos/Bash-Prompt/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO-2.html).

```
export PS1="$ "
```